# Comparing Cells in a row to see if adjacent cells have same values

Tags: excel, vba

Problem: My maximum Range is around 10000 Rows x 365 columns, I want to compare cell values across a row .

Conditions:

1. It has to return how many times a name is repeated in each row for every primary key
   if a name comes only once in a row, that need not be shown, anything more than 2 should be displayed
2. It has to exclude blank cells and if it encounters "Dispatched" then it need not count further.

Requirement: Any solution either excel or macro would do.

Sample Excel File

| Bag Number | 8th July | 9th July | 10th July | 11th July | 12th July | 13th July |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20/F/43352/1 | FILING | FILING | FILING | FINAL POLISH | FINAL POLISH | FINAL POLISH |
| 20/F/43352/2 | FILING | FILING | FILING | FINAL POLISH | FINAL POLISH | FINAL POLISH |
| 20/F/43352/3 | FINAL POLISH | QC | Dispatched | Dispatched | Dispatched | Dispatched |
| 20/F/43352/4 | Casting | Casting | Laser Cutting | Filing | Filing | FINAL POLISH |
| 20/F/43352/5 |  |  |  |  |  | Casting |
| 20/F/43352/6 |  |  | Casting | Casting | FINAL POLISH | Dispatched |
| 20/F/43352/7 | FILING | FILING | FILING | FINAL POLISH | FINAL POLISH | FINAL POLISH |

The Output for the same should be

| Bags | Casting | Filing | Final Polish | Dispatched |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20/F/43347/1 |  | 3days | 3 days | Yes |
| 20/F/43347/2 |  | 3days | 3 days | Yes |
| 20/F/43347/3 | 2 days | 3days | 3 days | Yes |

Background

1. Until very recently this process was manual so once this spreadsheet was made, it would be divided among 3 people and they would manually scan, highlight and proceed
2. Tried a countif condition, row wise but that again reduces 365 columns to 12 columns and leaves behind lots of unnecessary values, (if its in a station for only 1 day need not be highlighted)
3. Tried Pivot but did not give a summary that makes sense.
4. VBA is not my strong suite haven't tried anything there.
5. I am looking for something that will help make sense to this and highlight if any product is stuck anywhere.

Hi all, to answer all queries,

1. @braX I have tried countif with the department names, but the resulting table is unwieldy for my requirement. am looking for ideas to solve this
2. @DavidWooley-AST there are total of 12 departments, and the data is kept for an entire year, a primary key can go through each department in 45 days or more.

   Also there is a chance that incase of any rework then there is a revisit to the department. thus that data also has to be captured, sorry I should have mentioned this before.

Comment: "If a name comes only once in a row " - does that mean bag numbers or fillings/processed (or final polished) ? Interesting question but you need to give a better example. Your 43352 would give output 3 days 3 days , and 7 occurances. Right ?

Comment: My bad, Your 43352's example above would give output 3 days 3 days , for each and 1 occurance for each "/number" Right? . How many columns accrodd does/can the data go to ? Does it have multiple repeated filings/polished's ? I e can your data also look like this also : key, f,f,-,f,f,f,p,p,f,f,-,-f,-,f,f,f,f,f,p,p,p . 
 ..etc hence 2 days f, 3 days f, 2 days p, 2days f,4days f, 3days p   (Ignoring blanks and solitary days as you say )?

Comment: Otherwise , it would be relatively simple. Look for concurrent , repeating countif functions. Counting Distinct / repeating values   .  You've also got index match functions (or hlookup) across rows to find the cell reference of where "Dispatched" occurs and only count until then.

Comment: @David Wooley - AST please check edits for the question. sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the output you show using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365.

The below should get you started.

You will have to add some lines in the Table.Group Aggregation list for other tasks.

You may also need to add code to exclude non-repeats and after "Dispatched" but you showed no examples of that in your data or results, so I did not code anything for that.

I also don't know what you mean by "*highlight if any product is stuck anywhere*".

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let

//Replace table name in next line with the "real" table name in your workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table6"]}[Content],

//unpivot all except the "Bag Number" to => a three column table
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Bag Number"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

//remove unneeded Attribute column (the dates)
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"}),

//Group by Bag Number
//  then extract the Count for each type
//  Add " days" to each count
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Bag Number"}, {
        {"Filing", (t)=> "Filing " & Text.From(List.Count(List.Select(t[Value],each _ = "FILING"))) & " days"},
        {"Final Polish", (t)=> "Final Polish " & Text.From(List.Count(List.Select(t[Value],each _ = "FINAL POLISH"))) & " days"}
        }),

//Merge columns with commas (and hyphen for the first to the rest) to get final format
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Filing", "Final Polish"},
        Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(", ", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    #"Merged Columns1" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Merged Columns",{"Bag Number", "Merged"},
        Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" - ", QuoteStyle.None),"A")
in
    #"Merged Columns1"
```

[image]

***Edit based on your new example of data and desired output***

Given your new example, you can get the output from PQ as shown below.

Note that you can add the other departments using the same syntax as shown for those done (except for `Dispatched` which is treated differently).

**M Code**

```
let

//Replace table name in next line with the "real" table name in your workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table6"]}[Content],

//unpivot all except the "Bag Number" to => a three column table
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Bag Number"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

//remove unneeded Attribute column (the dates)
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"}),

//Change to proper case for consistency and text matching
    properCase = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Value", Text.Proper, type text}}),

//Group by Bag Number
//  then extract the Count for each type
//  Show null if count < 2
//  Add " days" to each count
//  Show only `Dispatched` if it occurrs one or more times
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(properCase, {"Bag Number"}, {
        
        {"Casting", (t)=> 
                        let 
                            x =List.Count(List.Select(t[Value], each _ = "Casting"))
                        in 
                            if x < 2 then null else Number.ToText(x) & " days", type text},

        {"Laser Cutting", (t)=> 
                        let 
                            x =List.Count(List.Select(t[Value], each _ = "Laser Cutting"))
                        in 
                            if x < 2 then null else Number.ToText(x) & " days", type text},

        {"Filing", (t)=> 
                        let 
                            x =List.Count(List.Select(t[Value], each _ = "Filing"))
                        in 
                            if x < 2 then null else Number.ToText(x) & " days", type text},

        {"Final Polish", (t)=> 
                        let 
                            x =List.Count(List.Select(t[Value], each _ = "Final Polish"))
                        in 
                            if x < 2 then null else Number.ToText(x) & " days", type text},

        {"QC", (t)=> 
                        let 
                            x =List.Count(List.Select(t[Value], each _ = "Qc"))
                        in 
                            if x < 2 then null else Number.ToText(x) & " days", type text},


        {"Dispatched", (t)=> 
                        let 
                            x =List.Count(List.Select(t[Value], each _ = "Dispatched"))
                        in 
                            if x = 0 then null else "Dispatched", type text}
    })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

Comment: I am new to power query so one doubt,

Comment: @allwynp I see you have radically changed your desired output, & it makes no sense. You have items in output that do not appear in input

Comment: that output was in regards to davids query,  there are multiple work station (12 in fact) I managed to get your code working for my specialized scenario. Its beautiful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have a doubt, when I try to close and load the query am getting this error message, no error message available, result code: -2146233052(0x80131524) any idea on what to do in this scenario???

Comment: @AllwynP  I've never seen that error code. The only relevant article I found was [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-2016-standard-error-when-i-load-to-table/668fa037-a2b5-4dae-a985-3476b1fbcbbf) where the recommendation was to do a repair of Excel with a link to the instructions to do that. If that doesn't work, suggest copying just the data to a new workbook, and running the query in that workbook.

Comment: @AllwynP And I will modify the query to provide output similar to what you show in your modified question.

Comment: apparently the error was due to non updating MS office. After updating the office, the error went away. Thanks

Comment: Rosenfield, while the first code  works perfectly (it gives counts of all the different stations correctly) but the second code only count of 2 or 3 stations are provided, any idea why this happens?

Comment: @AllwynP My guess would be some difference between your actual data and the example that you provided, or perhaps you made some modification to the code that is not accounting properly for your real data.  It certainly appears to work properly with the copy of your example, as shown in my second pair of screenshots.

Comment: @RonRosenfield, this would sound very innocent but did u write this code in advanced editor or did u use the group by GUI to add this, incase u used the GUI how did u do that??

Comment: @AllwynP Most of the important code was done in the Advanced Editor.